# Obtener dato seleccionado y pasarlo a un input de misma página

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo  obtener el dato que seleccione en 2 anteriores input [date] para pasarlo a un input [text], actualmente tengo una función que calcula la diferencia entre 2 fechas en días eso me funciona correctamente cuando los capturo directamente de la base de datos, pero cuando estoy ingresando (para registrar los días) me gustaría que también calculara los días restantes y los muestre en el input que tengo seleccionado

Adjunto el código:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Llegada</label>
                        <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control"  value="" type="date"  id="llegada" name="llegada" required=""  />

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Retiro</label>
                        <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="date" name="retiro" id="retiro" value=""   required="" >
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Días</label>
                        <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $restante?>" type="date"  id="restante" name="restante" required=""  />

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Este es el código que quiero capturar los datos de arriba, todo está en un formulario pero sin método Post ya que los necesito una vez que se actualice la fecha

```
<?php $restante = dias_pasados($_GET['llegada'],$_GET['retiro']);  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dadole vueltas a tu pregunta, siento que lo que quieres es algo con Javascript e hice esto, espero te sirva y se acomode a lo que buscabas. Saludos

```js
function calcula(){
var fechaInicio = document.getElementById('llegada').value;
var fechaFin    = document.getElementById('retiro').value;

if(isNaN(fechaInicio) && isNaN(fechaFin) ){
var diff = new Date(fechaFin).getTime()- new Date(fechaInicio).getTime();

  document.getElementById("diastotales").innerHTML =diff/(1000*60*60*24)
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>

  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Llegada</label>
                        <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control"  type="date"  id="llegada" name="llegada" required="" onchange="calcula()" />

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Retiro</label>
                        <div class='col-sm-10'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="date" name="retiro" id="retiro"   required="" onchange="calcula()">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


        <label>Total de dias:<span id="diastotales"></span></label>
       

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias , Además de funcionar me dio un indicio de como hacer otra cosa.